# I have some approximate integral calculation. Is there a clean way to prove it?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

Let: $P(R)=\int_R^{\infty}F(z)e^{-z}dz$ where $F(z)$ is the CDF of some discreate positive  R.V. denote by $U$.
Integrate by parts: $P(R)=(-F(z)e^{-z})_R^{\infty}+\int_R^{\infty}F'(z)e^{-z}dz$
The approximation here is that $F'(z)$ is problematic since $F(z)$ is a step function.
But, continue with the calculation:

$P(R)=F(R)e^{-R}+E(e^{-U}|U \geq R)P(U \geq R)=F(R)e^{-R}+E(e^{-U}|U \geq R)(1-F(R))$.
And this is what I want to have and it is well defined and for my examples it also true.

What is the correct way to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write $\int_R^\infty e^{-z}dF(z)=\sum_{z_k \ge R}e^{-z_k}P(U=z_k)$, then you will have no problems with the derivative.